# trying to understand the typical approach used for oauth tokens for this scenario

Tags: node.js, api-design

I'm in the process of putting together an app which leverages a third-party API.  The third-party API requires a bearer token as a parameter which it provides through a separate API.  The API documentation states that the bearer token expires after 5 minutes.

What is the typical intent/strategy in regards to an app leveraging an API with this type of input?  Eg is 5 minutes simply a generous buffer for reserving the use of a bearer token for a single subsequent API call?  Ie a unique bearer token should be secured before each API call?

Or is the general intent/strategy for this to somehow cache the bearer token for 4 minutes or so.  Make as many API calls that need to be made with that single bearer token, and then after a 4 minute timer, make a new API call to get a new bearer token - rinse and repeat?

Comment: I'd just cache the token and invalidate when you get an HTTP response indicating your token is expired. But I don't think there's an objective answer here.

Comment: interesting - thanks for that feedback.  i wasn't sure if there was a generally accepted best practice for that